# Anything analogous to Grand Central Dispatch outside of Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

In the past few months, while doing iOS development, I got really comfortable with using the so called [Grand Central Dispatch technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch) provided by default with ObjectiveC. With just a couple of simple calls, it allows me to do awesome things like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // Do stuff on the lowest priority queue here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do stuff with the above results here back in main thread/queue
    });
});
```

I can basically fork off tasks on other threads of custom priority whenever I feel like it, and I can use the result in any way I want without having to put much effort into passing objects between threads, terminating threads, joining on then etc. According to Wikipedia, a more general name of that approach is the "[thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)".

I feel like, as far as achieving parallelism is concerned, this is easier than a lot of other solutions I have used in the past (I'm thinking pthreads, but there's something analogous in most languages). I guess that a big part of the "ease of use" comes from the fact that iOS apps (OSX too? never wrote one myself) use run-loops and task queues for each thread, thus making work separable into discrete units, not something you generally start with in a blank program skeleton in most languages.

The question thus is, is there anything like GCD in other languages, or is it not a model popular outside of the Apple universe? I'm specifically interested in Clojure/JVM, since it does add a bunch of parallelization abstraction that might perhaps be analogous, but I'd love to know the same about other languages as well.

Comment: https://github.com/fusesource/hawtdispatch

Comment: I'm currently researching: http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/ w/ Kotlin

Answer (score 2):

Grand Central Dispatch is at its heart a thread pool. Most languages have something similar, though GCD is nicer than most IMO. The most popular equivalent Java library is Fork/Join. Clojure also includes a number of concurrency functions for handling specific tasks, but for more general concurrency you'll want Fork/Join.

Comment: [A Java Fork-Join Calamity][1]

It is well worth a read before you plan to use the ForkJoinPool in your own projects.


  [1]: http://coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html

Answer (score 0):

the dispatch API is in C and open source. so it isnt part of the objC runtime (though the runtime uses the dispatch api!)

something similiar.. mhm .... maybe the Parallel Task Lib Under Windows 8